# How can I switch between button styles (NSButtonCell)?

Tags: applescript-objc

I have a button with the following attributes:

Style: **Recessed**

Type: **Momentary Push In**

I would like to click on this button to change it to the type: toggle
(Highlighted)
and if I click on another button it goes back to the state of: **Momentary Push In**
so I did the following:
`myButtonOne's setButtonType:2`

going back to Momentary Push In:
`myButtonOne's setButtonType:7`

There are two problems:

1- When I click again, it takes two clicks for it to
can return to the toggle style.

2- The color of the text of the button title is black, I would like it to be white.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do, just programmatically highlight a button?

Comment: @red_menace, Yes, I want to programmatically highlight a button, with some specific color.

Comment: @red_menace, can you help me?

Comment: I still don't know what you are wanting to do with changing the type, but you can manually highlight the button.  To set a custom button color you are looking at subclassing it, or maybe use an alternate image or Core Animation layer.  The title text can be an attributed string, so you can do whatever you want there.

Comment: What I want to do is that when I click on a button it is highlighted.

Comment: Buttons normally do that.  If you are talking about highlighting another button, you can call its `highlight:` method, or if the same button maybe use a `NSPushOnPushOffButton` type.  This is sounding more like an [X-Y problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Thanks @red_menace, I solved this question in another way as I had already tried to use PushOnPushOff buttons could help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919189/how-can-i-insert-icons-in- a-sidebar